# Is there any difference between "margin: 0 auto;" and "margin: auto;"

Tags: css, cross-browser

When we want page's main container align center, we usually use `"margin: 0 auto;"`, but when I use `"margin:auto;"`, behaviour are the same in some browser I have (Google Chrome, Firefox).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Sets the element's left and right margins to `auto`, and the top and bottom margins to `0`.

```
margin: auto;
```

Sets *all* the margins to `auto`. You are probably getting the same behaviour due to your `<body>` being 100% height, hence the vertical `auto` margins have no effect.

Comment: The body's height (which is typically auto, not 100%) has no effect on how auto vertical margins are calculated. The spec simply defines auto vertical margins to *always* be zero on in-flow block boxes. So for in-flow block boxes, the answer to the question is not yes, but no - there is no difference between margin: 0 auto and margin: auto. The answer is only yes in one other specific case: absolutely positioned elements.