# How to centralize a table into a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a div, like this:
[image] 
I need to centralize the table inside this div... 
But my attemp to set the 'text-align:middle' fail, like this:[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: This is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skkhgzx4/

Comment: @JulioCesarBoaroli Aw man, why did you select his as the correct answer, when mine was there first? You picked mine first, but then changed it to his, even though they are the same. He changed his based on my fact (read the first comment of Steyn's answer). Come on :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `margin: 0 auto;` to your table, and the whole table will be aligned in the middle of the div.

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skkhgzx4/5/

Answer (score 2):

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Will fix everything for you!

Comment: Better to do `0 auto` instead of `auto`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8312397/2098652

Comment: Works man, thank you!

Comment: Could you explain why you do not have to set a `width` in order for this to work.

Comment: Take for example a paragraph of 500 characters. Without a defined width, it will just take up all the space it can, right? There is nothing to center, because the paragraph is 100% to it's parent. In this case, the table already has a pre-defined width (intentional or not). The input field and labels only take up as much space as they need, and will not fill to 100% of their parent. Hence, you won't need to set a (max)width.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with CSS

```
#table{
margin: 0, auto;
display: block;}
```

Other approach:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Other approach set table into a new div. Set width of new div to 80% of the parent div. In CSS from the new div, set display: block and margin: 0, auto.

If everything fails,

```
<center> table </center>
```

in HTML text will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

just set `display: inline-block;` on table and on parent `text-align: center;`

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/PPjKoW)

Answer (score -1):

Set a fixed width for your table container `div` (cheque) and give it `overflow:hidden` and `margin:0 auto;`

```
    <div id="cheque" class="content" 
    style="
      overflow:hidden;
      margin:0 auto; 
      width:300px"> ...
```

Your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skkhgzx4/3/

Comment: Suggesting inline CSS is bad, but it's even worse when the CSS is just wrong.

Comment: Come on, he's got inline CSS all over the place. I'm trying to fix the propblem not to teach proper coding practices.

Comment: When in this situation, you can show him the quick fix, like what you've done, explain why its bad and then show him the proper way to do it and advise him to follow your better approach. Just edit your answer if need be.